# Execution of a query in a function plpgsql (POSTGIS)

Tags: sql, postgis, postgresql-9.4

I'm looking for all the points that are inside a polygon. The query works for me, but when I add them to a function plggsql I get an error.

**Query Ok**

```
SELECT id, the_geom
FROM vialidad
WHERE ST_Contains('POLYGON((-99.1981315612793 19.357945,-99.1981315612793 19.376003,-99.161634 19.376003,-99.161634 19.357945,-99.1981315612793 19.357945))',   ST_AsText(the_geom));
```

**When I add the query to the function plpgsql and the polygon that was created is in polygon variable.**

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT id,the_geom FROM vialidad WHERE ST_Contains('||polygon||',ST_AsText(vialidad_cdmx_vertices_pgr.the_geom));'  
INTO nodes
USING polygon;
```

**Console Error**

```
QUERY:  SELECT id, the_geom FROM vialidad WHERE ST_Contains(POLYGON((-99.1981315612793 19.357945,-99.1981315612793 19.376003,-99.161634 19.376003,-99.161634 19.357945,-99.1981315612793 19.357945)),ST_AsText(the_geom));
```

> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_nodes_between_two_lines(integer,integer) line 37 at EXECUTE
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "19.357945"
>   SQL state: 42601

Many thanks in advance for any possible help.

Comment: have you tried passing the variable `polygon` between single quotes? `EXECUTE 'SELECT id,the_geom FROM vialidad WHERE ST_Contains('||quote_literal(polygon)||', ...`: assuming that `polygon` is a WKT literal.

Answer (score 1):

Do not concatenate strings into your SQL query. You are already passing the variable to the `execute` command with the `using` keyword, but your query doesn't use a place holder.

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT id,the_geom FROM vialidad WHERE ST_Contains($1,ST_AsText(vialidad_cdmx_vertices_pgr.the_geom))'  
--                                                          ^ here
INTO nodes
USING polygon;
```

The fact that you are selecting *two* columns but only supply a **single** target variable with the `INTO` clause is highly suspicious.

But I don't think you need dynamic SQL at all, assuming `polygon` **is** a variable, the following should work just fine:

```
SELECT id, the_geom 
  into id_var, geom_var
FROM vialidad 
WHERE ST_Contains(polygon,ST_AsText(vialidad_cdmx_vertices_pgr.the_geom))
```

---

Note that if you have a column named `polygon` in the table `vialidad` this is going to give you problems. You should rename your variable `polygon` then to have a different name. Many people simply put e.g. a `l_` in front of the variable names, `l_polygon` or a `p_` for parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when run query separately, there is single quote with the first argument of st_contains

```
ST_Contains('POLYGON((-99.1981315612793 19.357945,-99.1981315612793 19.376003,-99.161634 19.376003,-99.161634 19.357945,-99.1981315612793 19.357945))',   ST_AsText(the_geom));
```

But in console error there are no single quote around the polygon. You can try function with single quote inserted as

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT id,the_geom FROM vialidad WHERE ST_Contains('''||polygon||''',ST_AsText(vialidad_cdmx_vertices_pgr.the_geom));'  
INTO nodes
USING polygon;
```